# (Rails app Api) Send data via HTTP and receive JSON or XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http, url

I'm building a simple calculator for courier company. This calculator should receive some data via http request: weight, origin city and destination city. Then calculator should send back JSON or XML: price.

Sounds very simple, but I can't find any usable information how to handle with http request.

As I understand the request should be something like this:

```
localhost?weight=20&origin="Almaty"&destination="Moscow"
```

But I have no idea how to handle it with Rails. How to obtain these variables in HTTP?

Comment: these http request parameters can be handled using params object like `params[:weight]` , `params[:origin]` , `params[:destination]`. Do not put double quotes in your params values. Change it to `...?weight=20&origin=Almaty&destination=Moscow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use sockets so the client get make a http request, you receive it on your socket, compute it and send him back the result.

Documentation for  url attributes parser: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#M000075

this might help edit:

```
require 'cgi'

CGI::parse('param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3')


returns you sth like that:

{"param1"=>["value1"], "param2"=>["value2"]}
```